# Is there a list of OpenGL extension support?

Tags: opengl

I am looking for a list that states which vendor does support which OpenGL extension.

For example I wanted to use `ARB_shading_language_include`, which was accepted in 2013, but from various forums on the internet I assume it isn't implemented on AMD drivers. But I can't find any official document that states where this extension is supported.

Does such a list exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official list, but a community driven one. It is largely up to date:
https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php

As can be seen [here](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?extension=GL_ARB_shading_language_include) AMD doesn't support the `ARB_shading_language_include` extension at the time I wrote this answer.